# How to remove a character from key of array of objects in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, javascript-objects

I have a javascript object as follows:

```
result = [
   {"Account_ID__r.Name":"Yahoo Inc Taiwan","Contact_ID__r.Email":"jvernold@thestar.com"},
   {"Account_ID__r.Name":"WXIA-TV","Contact_ID__r.Email":"jwoolbright@11e.com"}
]
```

I need to remove the period(.) from the **keys** of the object. (Example: The key `Account_ID__r.Name` should become `Account_ID__rName`)

The above array should become as follows:

```
result = [
   {"Account_ID__rName":"Yahoo Inc Taiwan","Contact_ID__rEmail":"jvernold@thestar.com"},
   {"Account_ID__rName":"WXIA-TV","Contact_ID__rEmail":"jwoolbright@11e.com"}
]
```

I tried to construct a new array by using `for (var key of Object.keys(result)) { }` but it didn't work.

Code that I tried:

```
result.forEach(item => {
                    for (var key of Object.keys(item)) {
                        var keyWithoutPeriod = key.replace(/\./g,'');
                        this.datatableData.push({
                            [keyWithoutPeriod]: item[key] 
                        });
                    }
                });
```

It converted the code as follows:

```
datatable = [
   {"Account_ID__rName":"Yahoo Inc Taiwan"},{"Contact_ID__rEmail":"jvernold@thestar.com"},
   {"Account_ID__rName":"WXIA-TV"},{"Contact_ID__rEmail":"jwoolbright@11e.com"}
]
```

This is not in the format that I need. Please help. Thank You.

Comment: In your code, replace `this.datatableData.push()` line with `item[keyWithoutPeriod] = item[key]; delete item[key]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get entries, replace unwanted characters and build new objects.

```js
const
    data = [
        { "Account_ID__r.Name": "Yahoo Inc Taiwan", "Contact_ID__r.Email": "jvernold@thestar.com" },
        { "Account_ID__r.Name": "WXIA-TV", "Contact_ID__r.Email": "jwoolbright@11e.com" }
    ],
    result = data.map(o => Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(o).map(([k, v]) => [k.replace(/\./, ''), v])));

console.log(result);
```